# VB.Net Excel Pivot Filter

Tags: vb.net

I have one requirement: I have to apply a filter on pivot table filter to

1. select all dates of current month
2. current week
3. today

This is to be done using VB.Net.

Your help will be greatly appreciated, as I have been stumped by this for a long time.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I am able to add single date filter but I want to add filter to current month all dates available in filter colm

Comment: post a sample of what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are pulling data from a database, right.  Here's a simple example of how to do that.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim sql As String

    connectionString = "data source=Your_DB_Name;" & _
    "initial catalog=NORTHWIND.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders"
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    dscmd.Fill(ds)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Create a Pivot Table.

```
Private Sub CreatePivotTable(tableName As String)
    Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet = ExcelApp.Sheets.Add
    Dim ptName As String = "MyPivotTable"

    'We'll assume the passed table name exists in the ActiveWorkbook
    targetSheet.PivotTableWizard(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, _
        tableName, targetSheet.Range("A5"))
    targetSheet.Select()

    Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable = targetSheet.PivotTables(1)

    'To be professional or merely resuable, the name could be passed as parameter
    With pt.PivotFields("Order Date")
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Order Total"), "Order Count", _
        Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount)
    pt.AddDataField(pt.PivotFields("Order Total"), "Total for Date", _
        Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)

    '--OR--
    'AddPivotFields(pt, "Order Total", "Order Count", _
    '   Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount)
    'AddPivotFields(pt, "Order Total", "Total For Date", _
    '   Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum)

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pt)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(targetSheet)
End Sub
```

Filter a Pivot.

```
Sub FilterPivotTable()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "06/20/2019"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```